# How do I multiply and sum all values in two SQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sum

Let's say we have two tables.

```
1   0.73
2   0.13
3   0.14
```

and

```
1   1
2   1.465
3   1.181
```

I want to somehow loop through them in order to perform

> (0.73*1) + (0.13*1.465) + (0.14 * 1.181) = 1.08579

Or perhaps are there any SQL queries that would help with this?

Update: Here's a sample query. No syntax error, but doesn't seem to be returning anything though.

```
SELECT 
    sum(`racemean`.male * `racehazard`.male) 
FROM 
    `racemean` 
JOIN 
    `racehazard` ON `racemean`.male = `racehazard`.male
```

I'm not sure what format to show sample data, but this is exported from phpMyAdmin.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3ac2

Comment: Why you multiplied male * male and then joining table with male again? Where's the column `ID`?

Comment: -> `... JOIN racehazard ON racemean.race = racehazard.race`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the tables are connected by a column that can be used to `join`, the query below should work.

```
select sum(t1.col2 * t2.col2)
from t1 join t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1
```

[Fiddle with sample data](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5e17/1)

[Fiddle with the data from question](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3ac2)

Comment: What happens if the columns have different amounts of rows? Nevermind, I take back that question. It would never be different

Comment: all of them would be multiplied.

Comment: Note if they were different the INNER JOIN statement being executed here would ignore non-matching records in either table.  so if table `a` had records 1,3 and table `b` had 1,2 you would only get (0.73*1) as the other records wouldn't be considered.

Comment: yes @xQbert..i felt the op was asking what if there were 2 values for a particular id? and hence the comment, all the corresponding values would be multiplied

Comment: @vkp sorry, I worded it poorly. I meant, what if each table had different amount of rows. Also, I updated my question with a sample query if you could take a look.

Comment: please do post some sample data from both the tables as well

Comment: note that in the query you posted you were multiplying and joining on the same column.

Comment: @vkp posted some sample data

Comment: see the fiddle which says 'Fiddle with data from question'..the problem is you were `join`ing on `male` column. It should have been on `race` column instead.

Comment: @vkp ahhh. now the query makes more sense. Thank you.